# Lognormal distribution question calculating mean through integration

Tags: calculus, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

I have the following Lognormal PDF, where $\mu = 154$, and $\sigma = 117.21$.

$f(x) = \frac{0.00340365 e^{-0.0000363949 (\log (x)-154)^2}}{x}$,

Since I only care about the interval $x \in [1,609]$, I normalized this density to calculate a normalization constant of $N = 0.00954002$. So, my modified density function becomes:

$f(x) = \frac{0.356776 e^{-0.0000363949 (\log (x)-154)^2}}{x}$.

Now, my confusion arises, because, if I calculate the expected value:

$\int_{1}^{609} x f(x) dx$,

I get (through Mathematica's numerical integration), 97.1369.

Since this is an expected value, should it not be closer to the 154 I set above?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No it should NOT be close to 154. For starters, even if you were not truncating the range, $\mu$ represents the mean on the log scale (similarly $\sigma$). The (untruncated) mean of your specified distribution is $e^{\mu+\frac12\sigma^2}=\exp(154+117.21^2/2)$, which is about $1.2\times 10^{3050}$

Also, beware, the lognormal can have a heavy tail and truncating often doesn't have a small effect unless $\sigma$ is quite small.

You may want to read the Wikipedia page on the lognormal to get you started.